# Does Firefox or Chrome work on this O/S

Tags: firefox

I installed Elementary O/S on my 2007 macbook, found it is very slow and the Built in browser does not work. Is there a version of Firefox or Chrome that work on this O/S ? I want to try this O/S on that old machine, but having a browser that will not connect to the internet. Otherwise it is useless.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they both work great on elementary. I'm using the beta of Firefox Quantum without issue and both the stable and dev version of Chrome. Again, they both run great.

You can download Firefox from the App Center. To install Chrome you can either install via:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

or manually download the .deb file from the Chrome website and then in elementary install Eddy from the App Center to install the deb file.

But honestly if you're trying to install this on a 2007 machine you might have some issues unless you go with something really lightweight. I would recommend Xubuntu or Lubuntu. Something that runs a lighter desktop.